# instantiating a composite class from an instance method Ruby

Tags: ruby, instantiation, composite

I'm playing with ways of enforcing class relationships in Ruby before I start writing out the code over the weekend. I'm trying for a composite relationship, but one that I have some measure of control over the PriceSeries class from outside the Commodity class.

Obviously this isn't it, but is there a reason to have a set up like this? Am I right in thinking that this would make for private data and perhaps would be suitable to store passwords for a user instance (for example)?

```
class ExcelFile
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end


class Commodity 
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def new_price_series(name, source)
        name = PriceSeries.new(name, source)
    end

    class PriceSeries
        attr_accessor(:name) #Without this line, is there any point of this class??

        def initialize(name, source)
            @source = source
            @name = name
        end
    end

end



mm8_prices = ExcelFile.new("some_exlsx_file")
gold = Commodity.new("gold")
gold.new_price_series(:xau, mm8_prices)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain what you mean by 'enforcing class relationships in Ruby' and 'a composite relationship'?

Defining a class within another class in Ruby, as you have done in the example, does not give either class special privileges over the other, it simply namespaces the 'inner' class.  i.e. `PriceSeries` (when referenced outside of `Commodity`) would be `Commodity::PriceSeries`.

This is different from defining inner classes in languages such as C# and Java.

Comment: what is that difference? (i've only used ruby/python/php and javascript). I want to make it clear when coding that a PriceSeries instantiation belongs to a commodity and cannot exist without one - but a commodity can exist without a priceSeries. Also, t[here can be many PriceSeries per commodity. I think I've actually found a way to do this using metaprogramming to create instance methods in the Commodity class that are PricePoint objects. Is this a good way of doing that?

Comment: In your example, you have simply defined a class called Commodity::PriceSeries.  There is no special relationship between Commodity and PriceSeries or instances of them - PriceSeries can be instantiated by code outside of Commodity using Commodity::PriceSeries.new(name, source).  To enforce a relationship, pass a Commodity instance to the PriceSeries constructor.  Your Commodity instance can also maintain a collection of PriceSeries instances.  This is standard OO and should not require any metaprogramming.